# Angular distribution of dipole moments?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Please tell me if my reasoning is correct. The energy of a dipole in an electric field is given by $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{E}=-aE\cos(\theta)$. For a collection of non-interacting dipoles in a thermodynamic system, the angular distribution is just given by the Gibbs-Boltzmann factor:

$$f(\theta)=Ae^{\beta aE\cos\theta}$$

where $\beta$ is the inverse temperature and $A$ is the normalization coefficient:

$$A=\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\beta a E \cos\theta} d\theta=2\pi I_0(\beta a E)$$

The normalization constant seems too complicated/weird. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hamiltonian of a rigid rotor electric dipole is given by

$$H=\underbrace{\frac{p^2}{2m}}_{\text{translation}}+\underbrace{\frac{L^2_{\theta}}{2mR^2}+\frac{L^2_{\phi}}{2mR^2\sin^2\theta}}_{\text{rotational}}-\underbrace{2qRE\cos\theta}_{\text{dipole-field interaction}}$$

We see that the $(\theta,L_{\theta})$ conjugate variables don't separate cleanly from the $(\phi,L_{\phi})$ conjugate variables in the Hamiltonian, i.e. we have to talk about the distribution along the $\theta$, $\phi$, $L_{\theta}$, and $L_{\phi}$ coordinates all together. This will actually work in our favor.

Ignoring the translational part of the partition function, we have:

$$\begin{align}
Z_{\text{rot+dip-field}}&=\frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^2}\int e^{-\frac{\beta L^2_{\theta}}{2mR^2}-\frac{\beta L^2_{\phi}}{2mR^2\sin^2\theta}+2\beta qRE\cos\theta}\,dL_{\theta}dL_{\phi}d\theta d\phi\\
&=\frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^2}2\pi\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{\beta L^2_{\theta}}{2mR^2}}dL_{\theta}\right)\left(\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{2\beta qRE\cos\theta}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{\beta L^2_{\phi}}{2mR^2\sin^2\theta}}dL_{\phi}\right)d\theta\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^2}2\pi\left(\sqrt{\frac{2\pi mR^2}{\beta}}\right)\left(\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{2\beta qRE\cos\theta}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2\pi mR^2\sin^2\theta}{\beta}}\right)d\theta\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^2}2\pi\frac{2\pi mR^2}{\beta}\int_{-1}^{1}e^{\alpha\cos{\theta}}\,d(\cos\theta),\,\,\,(\alpha=2\beta qRE)\\
&=\frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^2}2\pi\frac{2\pi mR^2}{\beta}\frac{2}{\alpha}\sinh(\alpha )\\
&=\boxed{\frac{mRT^2}{\hbar^2qE}\sinh\left(\frac{2qRE}{T}\right)}
\end{align}$$

The true distribution in $\theta$ can be just read off the above calculation by stopping short of the final $\theta$ integration and dividing by the partition function.

$$\boxed{f(\theta )=\frac{\alpha}{2\sinh(\alpha )}e^{\alpha \cos(\theta )}\sin(\theta )}$$

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. You have to integrate in the spherical angle. Using spherical coordinates $(\theta, \varphi)$.

For example the classical canonical distribution  we have $p(\theta)= \frac{e^{\beta pE\cos(\theta)}}{Z}$, where $p=qa$ is the dipole moment.
This function $Z$ (partition function) is given by
\[
Z= \int_0^{\pi} e^{\eta\cos\theta}\sin(\theta)d\theta \int_0^{2\varphi}d\varphi= \frac{2\pi}{\eta}\int_{-\eta}^{\eta}e^udu=\frac{4\pi}{\eta}\sinh(\eta),
\]
where $\eta=\beta pE$ and we used the change of coordinates $u=\eta\cos\theta$.

For ex. we can get the average potential energy in this distribution
\[
\langle -\vec p\cdot E\rangle= -pE\langle\cos\theta\rangle,
\]
where 
\[
\langle\cos\theta\rangle=\frac{1}{Z}\int_0^{\pi}  e^{\eta\cos\theta}\cos\theta\sin\theta d\theta \int_0^{2\varphi}d\varphi=\frac{\partial}{\partial\eta}\ln Z=\coth(\eta)-1/\eta
\]

Comment: This seems right, but I'm skeptical. We have conjugate pairs $(x,p_x)$, $(y,p_y)$, $(z,p_z)$, $(\theta, L_{\theta})$, $(\phi, L_{\phi})$. So we must integrate over those variables. I think the only way you can get the $\sin(\theta )$ term in the integral is through the Jacobian of the transformation from $(x,y,z)\rightarrow (r,\theta,\phi )$, but that is not what we're doing.

Comment: For example, the position is given by the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates. When we integrate over these coordinates we get the volume element $dxdydz$, which we can transform to $r^2\sin\theta\,drd\theta d\phi$.  For the orientation of the particle we **start** with the orientation $(\theta,\phi )$ coordinates, set by the use of $L_{\theta}$ and $L_{\phi}$ angular momenta. So when we integrate over the orientations we have $d\theta d\phi$, no $\sin\theta$.

Comment: I was already doing the integral on the spherical angle, since the dipole moment can take any orientation in the 3d space. The linear momentum will modify the result. The $r$ part cancels out. On the other hand, you made a good point on the angular momentum part. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_rotor for the angular momentum contribution. Also, one can verify the classical result  as a limiting case of the quantum version.

Comment: Correction: The linear momentum will **not** modify the result, since the translational kinetic energy doesn't get mixed with the angular coordinates. The rotational kinetic energy though will interfere with the resulting integration of the statistical averages. The $r$ part cancels out, actually it only enters the problem if you allow the dipole to move around.

Comment: @minmax Thanks! I actually solved it by reminding myself of the proper form of the hamiltonian for a rigid rotor. See my answer.